# detect paragraphs of pdf files using itext

Tags: pdf, itext7, paragraph

I need detect paragraphs from pdf files with iText 7. I know the following methods can be used for calculate difference between text lines:
`TextRenderInfo.GetBaseline()`,
`TextRenderInfo.GetAscentLine()`,
`TextRenderInfo.GetDescentLine()`

I have the following test text:
[image: Example]

How can I define the first line as the first paragraph and the next lines refer to the second paragraph.

Comment: The file you attached is a bitmap image, not a PDF. iText is for PDF processing.

Comment: This is a screenshot